# Replace string in links that are located in between / and ? with unique new string for each

Tags: javascript

UpdatedWe are using a software where I cannot directly edit the links. I need to be able to target the string within the link that is in between / and ?, so in the example below I need to be able to change login to welcome#travel. In the second example I would need to change "reg" to welcome#agenda. In the 3rd example login would change to faq I know this seems odd, but we are having an issue with the way the software outputs anchors and there is no solution in the product itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="1"><a href="https://test.com/directory/login?id=12345">Travel Info</a></li>
  <li class="2"><a href="https://test.com/directory/reg?id=54321">Agenda</a></li>
  <li class="3"><a href="https://test.com/directory/login?id=11111">FAQ</a></li>

 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So you want `.../welcome#agenda?id=54321`? That's not likely to work well, because the query string `id=54321` needs to be sent to the server, but nothing after `#` is sent to the server.

Comment: Is there a specific correspondence between the original string and the replacement? Or a list of replacements? WHere does `welcome#agenda` come from?

Comment: @barmar, I am trying to only grab what is in between the / and ? if that is possible as to not touch the id. There isn't a correspondance unfortunately, there is an issue with the way the software sets up anchor tags so we are looking for a work around. I was wondering if there is a way to target the text in between / and ? to do this. It may be a lost cause.

Comment: Use a simple regular expression: `[^/]+(?=\?)`

Comment: Or use a couple of calls to `split()`. First split on `/`, getting the last element. Then split that on `?` and get the first element.

Comment: Anytime someone wants to manipulate a link using regex I recommend taking a look at the javascript [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL) (that 3limin4t0r mentions in an answer) which picks apart the URL for you.

Answer (score 1):

Like stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949703/replace-string-in-links-that-are-located-in-between-and-with-unique-new-stri#comment137421348_77949703) normally the hash in the URL should come after the search/query parameters. If it's after a `#` it will be part of the URL hash, not of the query parameters.

Since you tagged the question with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) I assume you're looking for a JavaScript solution. In which case you can select your elements with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You could pass `a[href^="https://test.com/directory/"]` as the query selector, which selects all `<a>` tags of which the `href` attribute begins with `https://test.com/directory/`.

After you've selected your elements you can use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface to mutate the URL with relative ease.

Make a collection of replacements. Then for each `<a>` tag that matches the criteria, grab the replacement out of the collection and replace the last path segment and hash.

```js
const urlReplacements = ["welcome#travel", "welcome#agenda", "faq"];
let urlReplacementsIndex = 0;

const aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="https://test.com/directory/"]');
for (const a of aTags) {
  const href = new URL(a.href); // store the href as URL instance
  const path = href.pathname.split("/"); // store the path as an array
  
  // [optional] remove trailing slashes (not needed in the given context)
  while (path.length && !path[path.length - 1]) path.pop();
  // [optional] skip the iteration if the path does not have 3 segments
  // {root}/directory/(login|reg)
  if (path.length !== 3) continue;
  
  // get the replacement data and increment the index
  const [lastPathSegment, hash] = urlReplacements[urlReplacementsIndex++].split("#");
  path.splice(-1, 1, lastPathSegment);  // replace the last path segment
  href.pathname = path.join("/"); // update the URL with the new path
  href.hash = hash || ""; // add the hash to the URL (or use an empty string if there is none)
  a.href = href.toString(); // update the <a> href attribute
}

for (const a of aTags) console.log(a.href);
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="1"><a href="https://test.com/directory/login?id=12345">Travel Info</a></li>
  <li class="2"><a href="https://test.com/directory/reg?id=54321">Agenda</a></li>
  <li class="3"><a href="https://test.com/directory/login?id=11111">FAQ</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I left out that the string that needs to be changed can be the same for each, updated this in my question. I will work with this though, thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer to conform to the new "faq" criteria.